# Android – How can I Move a Layout Partially Offscreen?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to make a sliding menu in an android application I am building for my school, and whenever I open the menu, the menu button, in addition to the other views I've tried, are scaled to fit in the remaining 25% of the layout still on the screen.  So my question is, how can I disable this scaling so views can be moved offscreen along with their parent layout?

This is the XML file of the layout I am trying to move.  It contains the misbehaving button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/background_color"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/menu_button"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_button"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what the menu looks like closed:

[image]

This is how it looks when opened:

[image]

And this is how I want it to be when opened.  Notice the menu button has moved offscreen.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

Although it may work for a single button, I do not want to make the views invisible, I would like to move them off the screen to the right.  If, for example, I wanted to add a TextView that fills a horizontal row on the layout, the TextView would be scaled to 25% of the screen upon opening the menu.  Instead, I want it to retain the size and shape of all views and make them move partially off screen.

Comment: are to using animation on your menu button screen also?

Answer (score 0):

When menu opens up, set the visibility of menu icon to GONE

```
icon.setVisibilty(View.GONE);
```

and when close , again set visibility of icon to VISIBLE.

```
icon.setVisibilty(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I do not want to render my views invisible, I want to move them offscreen.  If I try to add other views, they are scaled to fit in 25% of the screen instead of moved partially off of it.

Comment: are you using navigation drawer or a custom layout?

Comment: I am not using a drawer, I am using a layout that is moved via animation then has its layout parameters changed to match the end of the animation.

Comment: Have you considered using fragment instead, because it gives you flexibility otherwise you can hide the layout you don't want while the other is visible and vice versa

Comment: Fragments were the first thing I tried.  However, it takes an eternity to change a fragment, and the app changes layouts rapidly.  Fragments are too slow and simply changing a layout in one large activity allowed interfaces to be changed instantaneously.